# Unset session, logout and destroy on btn press

Tags: php, logout, isset

So I got a button with name="logout". Am I missing something here?

```
if (isset($_POST['logout'])) { 
        session_unset($_SESSION['CurrentUser']); 
        session_destroy(); 
        echo 'you have been logged out.';
}
```

Comment: you have a question?

Comment: `session_unset()` clears all sessions. use `unset($_SESSION['CurrentUser']);`

Comment: What is the issue here?

Comment: I want unset all variables/sessions.

Comment: so when session is cleared/unset removes $outp if(isset($_SESSION['CurrentUser'])) {echo $outp.'<br>';} else{echo 'Please enter password to check this stuff out. person.';}